# EditText Inputs don't work when stored as a string,or passed in a Bundle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-edittext, bundle

I am Making a Basic form to take user input send it to different Activity and display it there ,When I use edittext to take a input store it in String variable and then send it  A blank string gets send,There seems to be no error or warnig in code can someone help,Also while testing the string using a toast  if I pass fullname(see code) as Editable and then convert is to String using toString() it works,but if I declare it as a string beforehand and then pass to toast again a blank output
This is my FormActivity

```
package com.example.formapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.textservice.TextInfo
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
import java.util.regex.Pattern

class FormActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var named:EditText
    private lateinit var emailadd : EditText
    private lateinit var branch : EditText
    private  lateinit var desc : TextInputEditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form)
         named =findViewById(R.id.name)
        emailadd  =findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress)
         branch=findViewById(R.id.branch)
        desc  =findViewById(R.id.bio)
        val fullName = named.text.toString()
        val email= emailadd.text
        val branchName = branch.text
        val biot= desc.text.toString()
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("key1", named.text.toString())
        bundle.putString("email", email.toString())
        bundle.putString("branch",branchName.toString())
        val intent  = Intent(this,DataPoint::class.java)
        intent.putExtras(bundle)



        val bSumit : Button =findViewById(R.id.submit)

        bSumit.setOnClickListener {
            val isAllinfoCorrect = Checkinfo();
            if(isAllinfoCorrect)
            {

                startActivity(intent)
                Toast.makeText(this,fullName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Please Enter the required fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun Checkinfo(): Boolean {
        var text = named.text.toString()
        if(text.isEmpty())
        {
            named.setError("Field Required")
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            named.setError(null)
        }

        text = emailadd.text.toString()
        val chekmail = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+"
        val expression = "^[\\w.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$"
        val pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
        val matcher = pattern.matcher(text)
        if(!matcher.matches() || text.isEmpty())
        {
            emailadd.setError("Please Enter a Valid Email")
            return false

        }
        else
        {
            emailadd.setError(null)
        }
        text=branch.text.toString()
        if(text.isEmpty())
        {
            branch.setError(" Field Required")
            return false
        }
        else
        {
            branch.setError(null)
        }
        return true

    }
}
```

This Is my second activity where I am using bundle

```
package com.example.formapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class DataPoint : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var name : TextView
    private lateinit var email : TextView
    private lateinit var Branch : TextView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_point)

      val bundle = intent.extras
        val nmaseString= "TEST STRING"

        name=findViewById(R.id.username)
        email=findViewById(R.id.emailAddress)
        Branch = findViewById(R.id.branchname)
        name.setText(bundle?.getString("key1","THIS IS A DEFAULT VALUE"))
        if (bundle != null) {
            email.setText(bundle.getString("email","Default"))
            Branch.setText(bundle.getString("branch","Default"))
        }


    }
}
```

this is the output
[image]

xml for datapoint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DataPoint">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="350dp"

        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/black"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.262"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"


        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.436">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:text="NAME"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"

            android:translationY="50dp"
            tools:visibility="visible"></TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"


            android:translationY="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/branchname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            android:translationY="150dp" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are creating the Bundle and Intent ahead of time.
In **onCreate** the EditText values are still empty.

Instead, create the Intent & populate the Bundle just before calling the **startActivity** method.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form)
    named =findViewById(R.id.name)
    emailadd  =findViewById(R.id.editTextTextEmailAddress)
    branch=findViewById(R.id.branch)
    desc  =findViewById(R.id.bio)
    val bSumit : Button =findViewById(R.id.submit)

    bSumit.setOnClickListener {
        val isAllinfoCorrect = Checkinfo();
        if(isAllinfoCorrect)
        {

            val email= emailadd.text
            val branchName = branch.text
            val biot= desc.text.toString()
            val fullName = named.text.toString()

            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("key1", named.text.toString())
            bundle.putString("email", email.toString())
            bundle.putString("branch",branchName.toString())

            val intent  = Intent(this,DataPoint::class.java)
            intent.putExtras(bundle)

            startActivity(intent)
            Toast.makeText(this,fullName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Please Enter the required fields",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: But if I store fullname as named.text and use it on else part in toast it works so why does it work there and not in bundle?? Anyway thanks

Comment: Look closely (in your code) at where the Toast call happens and where the bundle is created. The Toast happens upon button click, while the bundle is created and populated before button click and even before the view is visible (onCreate)

Answer (score 0):

Move this part of code...

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("key1", named.text.toString())
bundle.putString("email", email.toString())
bundle.putString("branch",branchName.toString())
val intent  = Intent(this,DataPoint::class.java)
intent.putExtras(bundle)
```

Inside the listener part like this:

```
if(isAllinfoCorrect)
{
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("key1", named.text.toString())
    bundle.putString("email", email.toString())
    bundle.putString("branch",branchName.toString())
    val intent  = Intent(this,DataPoint::class.java)
    intent.putExtras(bundle)
    startActivity(intent)
    Toast.makeText(this,fullName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```